# Search match text in Elasticsearch SpringBoot by using percentage

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm a new Elasticsearch SpringBoot here. I don't know how to search match text in Elasticsearch SpringBoot by using percentage. For example, I have a text "Hello world". Can I set a percentage of 50% or 70% to match with my text? I try with property minimumShouldMatch already but it seems doesn't work for my case right now.
Anyone help me please, Thank

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `should` query, split your search phrase by term, and set `minimum_should_match` according to your pourcentage

**Example query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "my_field": "hello"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_field": "world"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_field": "i'm"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "my_field": "alive"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Will find `hello world`, `hello alive` etc...

To split a text in terms you should use _analyse of your index

**Analyze and split terms**

```
POST myindex/_analyze
{
  "field": "my_field",
  "text": "hello world i'm alive"
}
```

Which give you result like that to populate your query, and match term analyser with the query, if for example you use custom `analyzer`

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "hello",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "world",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "i'm",
      "start_offset" : 12,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "alive",
      "start_offset" : 16,
      "end_offset" : 21,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```